# How to exclude large number of IDs from an Elastic Search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on an app similar to Tinder. In ElasticSearch I have a collection of about half a million users and their locations). Whenever the user opens the app to search for nearby users I run an Elastic Search query over that collection. The query is fairly complex, it takes into consideration not only the location but also how active the user is or how many photos he has.

What I struggle with is how to exclude those users who the current user already swiped through from the query. A naive way to implement this would probably be to maintaint a nested array of user IDs as part of every user document in the index and exclude based on that. But as every user does dozens of thousands swipes that array could potentially grow super big, so it's not a scalable solution.

Is there a way to exclude large number of entities from an Elastic Search query based on their IDs which does not hurt performace?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the lookup feature of the Terms query: [Terms lookup mechanism](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup)

> When it’s needed to specify a terms filter with a lot of terms it can be beneficial to fetch those term values from a document in an index. A concrete example would be to filter tweets tweeted by your followers. Potentially the amount of user ids specified in the terms filter can be a lot. In this scenario it makes sense to use the terms filter’s terms lookup mechanism.

Comment: Works like a charm! So both answers do solve my problem sufficiently, but I'm selecting this one as a correct answer as it's a bit more elegant solution. Thank you very much

Comment: For the benefit of people coming to this question in the future, it would be nice to see that solution at work, which implements the terms lookup mechanism.

Comment: @Val I don't know if that is such a good idea. I have placed a link to the official help pages of elastic. There's a good example for this. If this feature changes in the future, their documentation will be updated, but my example probably not. I agree to copy documentation when the link points to third-party pages though.

Comment: The idea was just to show how you concretely apply the terms lookup mechanism to solve @MartinŠťáva's problem, nothing more. I wouldn't be too concerned with 3rd-party documentation going outdated. Most of SO questions would be concerned by this issue if it was really a concern.

Comment: @rvheddeg Does this solution still work when the terms array get into 10,000s or even millions of IDs? I'm looking for a solution to filter which can filter records by IDs which can be in millions

Comment: @touchaponk I use it in production with 2 lookup indexes and some of the documents have 10000 terms. It seems to me the only solution if you want to go that high. But if it will work performantly is another matter. Try it out...

Answer (score 16):

You can try adding the [`ids` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) into a `bool/must_not` clause of your complex query and see how it behaves.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
              ...                <--- your other "must" constraints
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "ids": {
                "values": [ "id1", "id2", "id3" ]  <--- your list of ids to exclude
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Working for me too, Could anyone help how this is working

Comment: Is there a way to fetch these `[ "id1", "id2", "id3" ]` with an inner query instead of directly passing in the query? Similar to what we do in SQL - `select * from store where id in (select id from fav_store)`

Comment: @sattu this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34604288/4604579