# Excluding users in a search, the most optimal way

Tags: elasticsearch, data-structures

I have two indexes, on for a collection of profiles, and another containing each users excludes, e.g. blocked profiles.

The per user exclude lists will be updated very often, while in comparison the profiles are seldom updated... In this situation it is recommended to separate the data in two indexes, as I understand it.

EDIT [2017-01-25]
This is the mappings for the two indexes:

**PROFILES MAPPING**

```
PUT xyz_profiles 
{
  "settings": { 
    "number_of_shards": 1, 
    "number_of_replicas": 0 
  },
  "mappings": {
    "profile": {
      "_all": {"enabled":false},
      "dynamic":"strict",
      "properties": {
        "profile_id":{"type":"integer"},
        "firstname": {"type":"text"},
        "age": {"type":"integer"},
        "gender":{"type":"keyword"},
        "height":{"type":"integer"},
        "area_id":{"type":"integer"},
        "created":{
          "type": "date",
          "format":"date_time_no_millis"
        },
        "location": {"type": "geo_point"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EXCLUDE LISTS MAPPING**

```
PUT xyz_exclude_from_search
{
  "settings": { 
    "auto_expand_replicas": "0-all"
  },
  "mappings": {
  "exclude_profile": {
    "_all": {"enabled":false},
    "dynamic":"strict",
    "properties": {
      "profile_id":{"type":"integer"},
      "exlude_ids":{"type":"integer"} 
    }
  }
}
```

**number_of_shards** is 1 since this is on a single node (my test server). 
**auto_expand_replicas** set to 0-all is to make sure that the exclude list it copied to all nodes. I am aware that this is superfluous on a single node, but I don't want to forget when this is implemented on the production cluster.

**exclude_ids** will be an array of integers (profile ids) to exclude from the search.

This is the part of a search where certain profiles are excluded using current users (id 3076) exclude list:

```
GET /xyz_profiles/profile/_search{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "terms" : {
          "profile_id" : {
            "index" : "xyz_exclude_from_search",
            "type" : "exclude_profile",
            "id" : "3076",
            "path" : "exclude_ids"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Being very new to Elasticsearch, I would very much like to know if this is the most optimal way of doing it. I imagine there are some very experienced people out there, who can pinpoint if my mappings or my search is missing something obvious that would improve performance.

For example, I haven't fully understood the analyze/not_analyzed part of mappings as well as using routings in the search.

Comment: Let us know how did you solve it please!

Comment: As you suggest, I should probably do some performance testing... If it turns out well, I will add my findings...

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, I think it's a quite common pattern but at the moment there is not much information about it on Internet.

I was in a similar situation some time ago and it was solved in a similar way to the one you propose. But I did not separate it in two indexes, just added an `exclude_ids` field to our `user` index. For example, let's say that when the user with id `1` is searching, we use a `Term Query` to check that id `1` is not inside `exclude_ids` of target users, a query like:

`{ "term": { "exclude_ids": 1 }`

After using it with around two million documents I found out that:

- **Search is fast**

  - Taking into account how the inverted index works I think this usage is correct
  - Search is done inside the same index (having to search in other indexes means checking more shards)
- **Updates are slow**

  - Each time an id is added to `exclude_ids` the whole document is reindexed, since [partial updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#partial-updates) to a document are not possible. If the `exclude_ids` array gets very long, the updates can become specially slow.
  - For the same reason, indexed data that is not usually updated is reindexed, like name or age.

In your case, since you are separating the exclude list in other index; as you said, the data that is not usually updated does not have to be reindexed each time. But the problem of arrays that grow indefinitely is still there.

Plus, taking into account the way you would do the query (with a Terms Query using [lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) I guess), filtering a big amount of data there is a possibility of ending with some overhead. But I'm not sure about this. This is discussed [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/term-lookup-filter-td4051654.html).

It's difficult to decide which one would escalate better with a huge amount of data, doing loading tests could be a good idea.

A way to solve the expensive updates problem could be not inserting `exclude_ids` in Elasticsearch, but inserting only the active users exclude lists in memory (using Redis or similar), setting a TTL to them. I supposed that the original data is still being stored in MySQL, so it can be taken from there and be inserted in memory each time it is necessary (for example, when a user becomes active). But I think this is not recommended since it seems that a Terms Query with many terms degrades the performance a lot (explained in this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18829)).

There is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990034/how-to-exclude-large-number-of-ids-from-an-elastic-search-query), but in my opinion there are many things that should be taken into account not spoken there. I would be happy to read more opinions about the search and update performance with big amounts of data.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! :-)

As you suggest, we could probably drop the exclude index and send the array of excludes with the search query, but that could increase the size of the query drastically. Some arrays could in time grow to thousands of id's. Is it not better to have ES store the arrays instead of sending them to ES with every query? After all, the search is a many-to-one relation as I only combine one exclude document with the user index.

Comment: I just found out than you can store the arrays in ES without indexing them (you just need to keep `_source` active). So to me it sounds like the best solution, as you say it's better than sending them in each query.

Comment: You insert the exclude_ids arrays in a new index created solely for that purpose. Then you use the Terms Query lookup mechanism setting the path to that index (explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html ).

The point here is that you don't need to index them as I said in my last comment. Then the only concern now is how would that query perform.